# Custom routing for subtask in Celery taskset

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to set subtask parameters "queue" and "routing_key" not in apply_async().

It is necessary in Taskset that each subtask went to custom queue and routing_key.

Looks like:

```
tasks = []
for item in items:   
    tasks.append(task_name.s((params).<method for set custom queue and routing_key>))
job = TaskSet(tasks=tasks)
```

Comment: You probably got downvoted because it's not easy to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too clear what is the question. If you are asking if you can give `routing_key` and `queue` arguments to subtasks you can if you use `subtask()` instead of `s()`.

From [subtask](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.subtask) doc:

> options – Additional options to Task.apply_async().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any of the `apply_sync` arguments in the subtask call.

See the "Calling API" in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#subtasks)